# Input и label в центре экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, form, валидация

Я создаю форму регистрации. Я столкнулся с проблемой. как сделать input шире без фиксированной ширины, например `width: 420px`. И input и label расположить в центр. Я хочу что-то вроде этого: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCW5e.png). Но сейчас у меня это: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9M3M.png).

---

**Мой html код:**

```
  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="title">Create an account</h1>
       
     <form className="form">
        <div className="form-outline">
            <label className="input-label">Your Name</label>
            <input
            name="username"
            type="text"
            className="input"
            value={input.username}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            onBlur={validateInput}
           />           
        </div>

        <div className="form-outline">
            <label className="input-label">Your Email</label>
            <input
              name="email"
              type="email"
              className="input"
              value={input.email}
              onChange={onInputChange}
              onBlur={validateInput}
            />
        </div>

        <div className="form-outline">
            <label className="input-label">Password</label>
            <input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              className="input"
              value={input.password}
              onChange={onInputChange}
              onBlur={validateInput}
            />
        </div>

        <div className="form-outline">
            <label className="input-label">Repeat your password</label>
            <input
              name="confirmPassword"
              type="password"
              className="input"
              value={input.confirmPassword}
              onChange={onInputChange}
              onBlur={validateInput}
            />
        </div>

        <div className="form-check">
            <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" />
            <label className="form-check-label">
                I agree all statements in
                <a className="terms" href="/#">Terms of service</a>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div className="button">
            <button className="btn">Create account</button>
        </div>

        <p className="have-account">
            Have already an account
            <a className="login-here" href="/#">Login here</a>
        </p>
    </form>
 </div>
```

**Мой CSS код:**

```
.container {
padding: 16px;
width: 80%;
margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
}

.title {
text-align: center;
font-size: 2.5rem;
color: #0d6efd;
}

.input-label {
color: #6c757d;
}

.form-outline {
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.input {
padding: 0.45rem;
margin: 0.3rem 0 1.3rem 0;
font-size: 1.25rem;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
display: block;
color: #212529;
line-height: 1.5;
border: 1px solid #ced4da;
transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.input:focus {
color: #212529;
border-color: #86b7fe;
outline: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

.form-check {
margin-bottom: 3rem;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
}

.form-check-label {
padding-left: 0.5rem;
font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.form-check-input {
border-radius: 0.25rem;
border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
width: 1.3em;
height: 1.3em;
}

.form-check-input:focus {
border-color: #86b7fe;
outline: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

.terms {
color: #0d6efd;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left: 0.2rem;
}

.terms:hover {
color: #0a58ca;
}

.button {
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
}

.btn[disabled] {
opacity: .65;
cursor: not-allowed;
}

.btn {
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
background-color: #0d6efd;
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
border-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.have-account {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.login-here {
color: #0d6efd;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left: 0.2rem;
}

.login-here:hover {
color: #0a58ca;
}
```

---

**Edited:**

Также я попробовал это:

```
.input-label {
color: #6c757d;
}

.form-outline {
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
flex: 1 1 auto;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Но label попал в середину экрана. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2yie.png) Для label `float: left` не работает. И так мне нужно разместить label слева, а input сделать шире.

[image after answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o01sQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы хотели получить что-то такое:

```css
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #0d6efd;
}

.form {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.input-label {
  color: #6c757d;
}


.input {
    padding: 0.45rem;
    margin: 0.3rem 0 1.3rem 0;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    color: #212529;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.input:focus {
color: #212529;
border-color: #86b7fe;
outline: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

.form-check {
margin-bottom: 3rem;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
}

.form-check-label {
padding-left: 0.5rem;
font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.form-check-input {
border-radius: 0.25rem;
border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
width: 1.3em;
height: 1.3em;
}

.form-check-input:focus {
border-color: #86b7fe;
outline: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

.terms {
color: #0d6efd;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left: 0.2rem;
}

.terms:hover {
color: #0a58ca;
}

.button {
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
}

.btn[disabled] {
opacity: .65;
cursor: not-allowed;
}

.btn {
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
background-color: #0d6efd;
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
border-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.have-account {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.login-here {
color: #0d6efd;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left: 0.2rem;
}

.login-here:hover {
color: #0a58ca;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Create an account</h1>
       
        <form class="form">
    <label class="input-label">Your Name</label>
   <input
                name="username"
                type="text"
                class="input"
   />           

            <label class="input-label">Your Email</label>
                <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
     class="input"
                />

            <label class="input-label">Password</label>
            <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                class="input"
            />

            <label class="input-label">Repeat your password</label>
            <input
                name="confirmPassword"
                type="password"
                class="input"
            />


        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" />
            <label class="form-check-label">
                I agree all statements in
                <a class="terms" href="/#">Terms of service</a>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button class="btn">Create account</button>
        </div>

        <p class="have-account">
            Have already an account
            <a class="login-here" href="/#">Login here</a>
        </p>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Я добавил изменения в свой код, но у меня label теперь отображаеться на одном уровне с input. Фото с примером добавил в пост.

Comment: @dkobzar а изменения в разметку вы внесли? я изменил и HTML